# Laravel - Trying to get property of Non Object when using DB::select

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use the `DB::select()` function in Laravel, but it gives me the following error:

[image]

the Profile.php class is a direct copy of User.php with the following changes:

```
protected $fillable = array('uid', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'fullname', 'works_at', 'worked_at', 'dob',
    'pob', 'sex', 'cellphone', 'suburb', 'city', 'province', 'country'
);

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'profiles';
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your problem isn't in the query statement itself, but in `Auth::user()->id` instead. `Auth::user()` most likely returns null which causes the exception to be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried but might work

```
$pro=DB::select(DB::raw("select * from profiles where uid=:uid"),array(":uid"=>Auth::user()->id));
```

Comment: -1 This is wrong in more than one way. DB::raw would not prepare the query, and the error has nothing to do with DB::select, as @kajetons correctly pointed out in his comment